# Transform DataFrame to nested dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, dictionary

I have a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(
[(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
(8,9,10,11,12,13,14),
(15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
],columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7'])
```

Where I want the row elements to be transformed to inputs in nested dicts:
This is my final desired result:

```
[{'one': {'f1': 1, 'f2': 2},
'two': {'f3': 3, 'f4': 4, 'f5': 5},
'three': {'f6': 6},
'four': {'f7': 7}},
{'one': {'f1': 8, 'f2': 9},
'two': {'f3': 10, 'f4': 11, 'f5': 12},
'three': {'f6': 13},
'four': {'f7': 14}},
{'one': {'f1': 15, 'f2': 16},
'two': {'f3': 17, 'f4': 18, 'f5': 19},
'three': {'f6': 20},
'four': {'f7': 21}}]
```

I can achieve this result by using list comprehension:

```
l1=[{'one':{'f1':e1,'f2':e2},'two':{'f3':e3,'f4':e4,'f5':e5},'three':{'f6':e6},'four': 
{'f7':e7}} for e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7 in list(df.to_records(index=False))]
print(l1)
```

But is there some cleaner way of achieving the same result without using list comprehension
like maybe an inbuilt function in pandas?

Comment: I don't really see the connection between your original dataframe and your desired result. Where do the word-number and f labels come from? What's the logic behind the varying sizes of the smaller dictionaries?

Comment: There is no logic behind the word number or the different sized dicts. The f:s are just the renamed columns.

Comment: You may wonder why the heck I’m renaming the columns. It’s just because the f1-f7 names should be considered as arbitrary and not necessarily the same as the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a mapping by creating a dictionary and then using the `apply` function method from Pandas. By using the dictionary to map, the transformation process is much easier and more understandable as well.

Here's how you can achieve it.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
     (8,9,10,11,12,13,14),
     (15,16,17,18,19,20,21)],
    columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7']
)

# Define the mapping
mapping = {
    'one': ['c1', 'c2'],
    'two': ['c3', 'c4', 'c5'],
    'three': ['c6'],
    'four': ['c7']
}

# Transformation function
def transform_row(row):
    result = {}
    counter = 1
    for key, cols in mapping.items():
        result[key] = {}
        for col in cols:
            result[key]['f' + str(counter)] = row[col]
            counter += 1
    return result

# Apply the transformation
transformed_data = df.apply(transform_row, axis=1).tolist()

print(transformed_data)
```

which results in

```
[{'one': {'f1': 1, 'f2': 2}, 'two': {'f3': 3, 'f4': 4, 'f5': 5}, 'three': {'f6': 6}, 'four': {'f7': 7}}, {'one': {'f1': 8, 'f2': 9}, 'two': {'f3': 10, 'f4': 11, 'f5': 12}, 'three': {'f6': 13}, 'four': {'f7': 14}}, {'one': {'f1': 15, 'f2': 16}, 'two': {'f3': 17, 'f4': 18, 'f5': 19}, 'three': {'f6': 20}, 'four': {'f7': 21}}]
```